# ÿ printed as EOF in txt file

Tags: c

I have a program designed to manage student records in a txt file. I am attempting to delete a student record. The program opens the file, reads the contents and prints them for the user to see. The user then enters an integer for which line they wish to remove. It then returns the new content for the user to see.

```
int deleteStudent()
{
    FILE *dOldFile, *dNewFile;//Original file and New temp file
    char ch;
    int deleteLine, temp = 1;

    dOldFile = fopen(fName, "r");//fName is name of file user enters in previous function
    ch = getc(dOldFile);
while (ch != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", ch);//Prints content of Original file for user to see
    ch = getc(dOldFile);
}
rewind(dOldFile);
printf(" \n Enter line number of the line to be deleted:\n>");
scanf("%d", &deleteLine);//user selects which line of file to be removed


dNewFile = fopen("copy.c", "w");
ch = getc(dOldFile);
while (ch != EOF)
{
    ch = getc(dOldFile);
    if (ch == '\n')
        temp++;
        if (temp != deleteLine) //except the line to be deleted
        {
            putc(ch, dNewFile); //copy all lines in file copy.c
        }
}
fclose(dOldFile);
fclose(dNewFile);
remove(fName);
rename("copy.c", fName);
printf("\n Student Records Remaining:\n");
dOldFile = fopen(fName, "r");
ch = getc(dOldFile);
while (ch != EOF)
{
    printf("%c", ch);
    ch = getc(dOldFile);
}
fclose(dOldFile);
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

The issue is, and I believe it may be an issue with my while loops, is the contents printed to the new and renamed text file from *fprintf* has the first character removed, and from what I understand, a symbol for EOF printed at the end of the edit. For example the original file had

> 23 John Smith 18 5555555 
>   24 Tom Costa 15 5555555
>   25 Barry West 35 5555555
>   26 Daren carr 22 5555555

If the user decides to delete line 3 for example. This is the result in the txt file

> 3 John Smith 18 5555555
>   24 Tom Costa 15 5555555
>   26 Daren carr 22 5555555ÿ

Comment: `ch` should be an `int`.

Comment: Read the manual for all functions that you use, including `getc`. Don't guess what they might do.

Comment: Thanks for picking up on that Cool Guy.
Sorry Kerrek SB, I'll try to make less assumptions in the future.

Comment: strongly suggest using 'getchar()' rather than 'getc()'.   Always check (!=NULL) the returned value from fopen() to assure the operation was successful,   'ch' is defined as a char, I.E. one byte, while 'EOF' is defined as 4 bytes as 0xFFFFFFFF.   So they will never match.   'temp' starts at 1 and in incremented before checking for a line number match.  This will result in 'off-by-one' errors as to which line is skipped.

Comment: strongly suggest getting input lines via 'fgets()' rather than 'getc();  in the loop that is re-reading the input file, char by char,

Comment: Very detailed and thorough comment @user3629249, I really appreciate this. Advice taken!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every thing is fine.Just replace the while loop with the while loop and delete the

```
 ch = getc(dOldFile);
```

before the while as shown :

```
dNewFile = fopen("copy.c", "w");
//ch = getc(dOldFile);    comment this out
while((ch = getc(dOldFile))!=EOF)
  {       
   if (ch == '\n')
    temp++;
    if (temp != deleteLine) //except the line to be deleted
    {
        putc(ch, dNewFile); //copy all lines in file copy.c
    }
   }   //modify while to make it better
  fclose(dOldFile);
  fclose(dNewFile);
```

Comment: Your previous answer, prior to being edited, worked perfectly. Why the edit? :)
I only ask because the most recent edit didnt work. Why the change from the do and while loops to a single while loop?

Comment: Sorry forgot to delete the extra getc in the loop..... Forgive me@Colesie. See it now.The reason to change do  while with while is to first check the condition and then to run the loop.

Comment: Wow, again its perfect. Thank you so much! :D